# "Smart" fast compression for archiving mixed content?

Tags: compression, zip, tar, 7-zip, archiving

I would like to backup a computer folder quickly to an archive format (e.g. tar, zip, 7z, gz, etc.). The folder contains many files:

Some are text files that can achieve a good compression ratio. For example, I know there's one folder consisting of large plain CSV/XML files that can be compressed from more than 1 GB to less than 100 MB.

Others are image and zip files that cannot be compressed further.

Currently, I either pack the whole folder to a tar file, which is very quick on an SSD, and seems to be I/O bound. However, this does not attempt any compression, and based on what I said above about many of my plain text files, is wasting lots of space by wasting the potential for compression.

My other option is use 7z or zip and choose the fastest compression option. I'm happy with the compression, but this is much slower than above and seems to be CPU bound.

Is there a way to achieve the best of both worlds, somehow compress the plain text files, but do not attempt to compress the zip, jpeg, png, etc., to achieve both speed and some compression?

I can definitely write a script to loop through all the files, but I'm hoping for a low effort way - maybe some sort of options to 7z on the command line? Bonus if it only depends on 7zip on Windows.

Comment: `tar` is not a compressor, so "nothing is compressed" seems normal. You can tell it to use a compressor though. Virtually any compression will be "slower than above" because `tar` without compression basically concatenates metadata, data and padding in one file. AFAIK there's no data checksumming, so the process is not CPU intensive at all, kinda like "`cat` with metadata". I guess `tar` can be even faster than copying files one-to-one because there's no need for opening multiple output files.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I was not clear but I know that `tar` is not a compressor. And as you have mentioned, the whole point of doing this is to make copying the entire archive faster, e.g. over FTP, because there is no overhead for many small files. However, it would be nice to both archive files to a single file AND achieve some compression, e.g. transferring over a slow FTP connection.